# Localization of d3.js (d3.locale example of usage)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to use `d3.locale()` in my app to display Russian names of months. 
http://jsfiddle.net/j2feJ/2/
Also, I need `shortMonths` variable to be in English, because they are in English in my database.

```
var ru_RU = {
    "decimal": ",",
        "thousands": "\xa0",
        "grouping": [3],
        "currency": ["", " руб."],
        "dateTime": "%A, %e %B %Y г. %X",
        "date": "%d.%m.%Y",
        "time": "%H:%M:%S",
        "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
        "days": ["воскресенье", "понедельник", "вторник", "среда", "четверг", "пятница", "суббота"],
        "shortDays": ["вс", "пн", "вт", "ср", "чт", "пт", "сб"],
        "months": ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"],
        "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
}
```

But display is still in English. Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Calling `d3.locale()` doesn't change the internal workings of d3, it just creates and returns a localization object. You need to capture this return value and store it in a variable so you can use it later. Given the object you created in your example code, you could do that like this:

```
var RU = d3.locale(ru_RU);
```

Then when you need a value to be localized, you must call for it explicitly. In your case, you want the full month names to be displayed as x-axis labels.

To do this, you can add a `.tickFormat()` to your x-axis, and specify that the format should be your localized version of a full month name.

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickPadding(8)
  .tickFormat(RU.timeFormat("%B"));
```

`locale.timeFormat()` is equivalent to `d3.time.format()`, except that it uses the locale that you created instead of defaulting to en_US. In this case `locale` is the variable `RU` which we created earlier.

Here is the updated [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PW48M/).

Remember, each time you want a localized string or value, you need to call for it explicitly. Use `locale.numberFormat()` in place of `d3.format()`, and `locale.timeFormat()` in place of `d3.time.format()`, where `locale` is a localization object created with `d3.locale()`. Hope that helps.

Comment: is there a way to use files that contains local data like those files and load them https://app.timersolutions.com/js/d3/src/locale/?

Comment: In D3 V4 this is done via d3.formatDefaultLocale(locale) where locale is the Object with local values like ru_RU. This is then automatically applied to d3.format(). E.g. d3.format(",") (thousand seperator as comma) will give a thousand seperator as "\xa0" if this is defined like that in Russian.