# D3.JS: Format as currency euro

Tags: d3.js

The [D3 Wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting) describes formatting, and how it's possible to format your numbers to dollar values using `d3.format("$.,2f");`. However, using `d3.format("€,.2f");` to format numbers to euro values does not work. What is the appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 13):

2016-07-06 edit: The answer below was valid for d3 v3. As of d3 v4, [`d3.formatLocale`](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#formatLocale) looks to be the equivalent to what `d3.locale` was.

---

The dollar sign should be kept, as it means "currency".

What you need to do is define the locale (cf. [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Localization.md)) using `d3.locale()` function (d3 defaults to `en-US`).

Here is an example where `en-US` parameters are kept for all properties, except for the currency, where the $ prefix got replaced by the `€` suffix ( done with: `"currency": ["", "€"]`):

```
var NL = d3.locale ({
  "decimal": ".",
  "thousands": ",",
  "grouping": [3],
  "currency": ["", "€"],
  "dateTime": "%a %b %e %X %Y",
  "date": "%m/%d/%Y",
  "time": "%H:%M:%S",
  "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
  "days": ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
  "shortDays": ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
  "months": ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
  "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
})
```

Then you can use `NL.numberFormat("$,.2f")` to format numbers as Euro.

[Working demo](https://tonicdev.com/5694f8711f12ba0d000d405e/5694f8711f12ba0d000d405f).

More information about `d3.locale` usage in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385582/localization-of-d3-js-d3-locale-example-of-usage).

Comment: currency mark is at trailing position, is there any way to put it in front of returned string

Comment: Yes, it's explained in the linked docs. Use `"currency": ["€", ""],` instead of `"currency": ["", "€"],`.